# Adding prefix of directory name to all rows of a column in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to add a prefix of a folder's name to all rows of a csv file. The aim is to combine [this](https://superuser.com/questions/768934/how-to-add-a-prefix-to-every-row-of-a-particular-column-in-a-csv-file-via-comman) awk command with the find command so I can automate it and apply it to all directories and subdirectories within a folder. Trying to output the result to a new csv file _prefix.csv to be safe.

```
find . -name "*.fasta"  -exec bash -c '
     for file do        
     prefix="${PWD##*/}" 
     awk -v a="$prefix" {if(NR==1){print; next}; $1="$a"_$1; print} %P >> %P_prefix.csv"
     done' _ {}
```

What I have:

```
27S_544
 - contigs.fasta
             ID | Rds 
         864585 | XX 

 - scaffolds.fasta
             ID | Rds 
         845335 | XX  


28S_545
  - contigs.fasta
             ID | Rds 
         867685 | XX  
  - scaffolds.fasta
             ID | Rds 
         867634 | XX
```

Desired output:

```
 27S_544
     - contigs.fasta
                  ID | Rds 
      27S_544_864585 | XX  

     - scaffolds.fasta
                  ID | Rds 
      27S_544_845335 | XX  


  28S_545
      - contigs.fasta
                   ID | Rds 
       28S_545_867685 | XX  

      - scaffolds.fasta
                   ID | Rds 
       28S_545_867634 | XX
```

Error

```
find: missing argument to `-exec
```

Comment: Even the highlight on stackoverflow is hinting you. You opened the `'` quotes, but then closed them.

Comment: Thanks I changed the original, now getting: find: missing argument to `-exec', clearly something slightly off with the structure

Comment: Sure, the `-exec` ends with a `;`. Like `-exec something something {} \;`. What is `%P` supposed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of dealing with complicated quotes, consider reading the stream line by line:

```
find . -name "*.fasta" |
while IFS= read -r file; do
     prefix="${PWD##*/}"
     # awk IS NOT bash
     #  in bash: "${a}_" to concatenate variable a with a _
     #  in awk:  a "_" 
     awk -v a="$prefix" '{if(NR==1){print; next}; $1 = a "_" $1; print}' "$file" >> "${file}_prefix.csv"
     # or just:
     # awk -v a="$prefix" 'NR!=1{$1=a"_"$1}1'
done
```

After getting hang of it, then re-escape it for a subshell when needed:

```
find . -name "*.fasta"  -exec bash -c '
     prefix="${PWD##*/}"
     awk -v a="$prefix" '\''{if(NR==1){print; next}; $1="$a"_$1; print}'\'' "$1" >> "${1}_prefix.csv"
 ' _ {} \;
```

I recommend reading [bashfaq/001](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) and revisiting the man page of `find` and research about `-exec` and `-printf` and re-reading introductions to `bash` and `awk` variables handling.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this script from base directory of your `.fasta` files:

```
while IFS= read -rd '' f; do
   d="${f%/*}"
   sed -i.bak "2,\$s~[^[:blank:]]~${d#./}_&~" "$f"
done < <(find . -type f -name '*.fasta' -print0)
```